# Replace character in parentheses with another

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I need to replace all occurrences of dots but only if the dot is in parenteses, with something else (semicolon for example), using python like this:

Input: `"Hello (This . will be replaced, this one. too)."`
Output:`"Hello (This ; will be replaced, this one; too)."`

Comment: Can the parentheses be nested? And what did you try?

Comment: You could do some research on using regex maybe ?

Comment: Presenting just the problem and no attempt to solve it typically attracts downvotes or close requests.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: Sorry, my first post, not a good one ig, I can replace it outside parenteses and replace the whole string inside parentheses but I could not combine the two together. Will try better next time, also, the parentesses will not be nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over characters in string, track number of opening and closing parentheses, only replace if more opening than closing parentheses encountered.

```
def replace_inside_parentheses(string, find_string, replace_string):
    bracket_count = 0
    return_string = ""
    for a in string:
        if a == "(":
            bracket_count += 1
        elif a == ")":
            bracket_count -= 1
        if bracket_count > 0:
            return_string += a.replace(find_string, replace_string)
        else:
            return_string += a
    return return_string


my_str = "Hello (This . will be replaced, this one. too, (even this one . inside nested parentheses!))."
print(my_str)
print(replace_inside_parentheses(my_str, ".", ";"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the parentheses are balanced and not nested, here's an idea with `re.split`.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = 'Hello (This . will be replaced, this one. too). This ... not but this (.).'
>>> ''.join(m.replace('.', ';') if m.startswith('(') else m
...:        for m in re.split('(\([^)]+\))', s))
...:        
'Hello (This ; will be replaced, this one; too). This ... not but this (;).'
```

The main trick here is to wrap the regex `\([^)]+\)` with another pair of `()` such that the splitting-matches are kept.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but this should work.

```
def sanitize(string):
    string = string.split("(",1)
    string0 = str(string[0])+"("
    string1 = str(string[1]).split(")",1)
    ending  = str(")"+string1[1])
    middle  = str(string1[0])

    # replace second "" with character you'd like to replace with
    # I.E. middle.replace(".","!")
    middle  = middle.replace(".","").replace(";","")

    stringBackTogether = string0+middle+ending
    return stringBackTogether

a = sanitize("Hello (This . will be replaced, this one. too).")
print(a)
```